# How to refresh WPF Toolkit ColumnSeries Chart in real time

Tags: c#, wpf

Application successfully Adds and Clears data from ColumnSeries WPF chart, but fails to re-add post Clear. Setting DataContext to null prior as advised elsewhere didn't resolve issue. Below is code and thanks for your assistance:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
        {
            dataToChart = new Input();
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = dataToChart;
        }

    private void Button_Click_Clear(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var series in columnChart.Series.OfType<Series>())
                {
                    series.DataContext = null;
                }
                columnChart.Series.Clear();
                dataToChart.Clear();
        }

    private void Button_Click_Add(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            dataToChart.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Test", 10));
        }
}
```

Input.cs

```
public class Input
{
    public ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, int>> ValueList { get; private set; }

    public Input()
    {
        this.ValueList = new ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
    }

    public void Add(KeyValuePair<string, int> data)
    {
        ValueList.Add(data);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        ValueList.Clear();
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
        xmlns:chartingToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit" 
        x:Class="IES_Console.MainWindow"
        x:Name="wndMain" Title="IES Console" AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None"  WindowStartupLocation="Manual" ResizeMode="NoResize" Background="Transparent" Foreground="{x:Null}" Loaded="Window_Loaded" Closing="Window_Closing" KeyUp="Window_KeyUp" MouseLeftButtonDown="Window_MouseLeftButtonDown" SizeChanged="Window_SizeChanged" LocationChanged="Window_LocationChanged" Icon="/IES%20Console;component/48x48.ico" MouseLeave="wndMain_MouseLeave" mc:Ignorable="d" FontFamily="Arial" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">


    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" Background="Black" ShowGridLines="False" Width="531" Height="700"  VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">

        <!--Code taken out for simplicity-->


        <Grid x:Name="subFooter" Grid.Row="3" Background =" Black" Margin="0,20,0,-144">


            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1"  VerticalAlignment="top" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                Text="TextBlock" Foreground="White" Width="511" Height="50"/>

            <chartingToolkit:Chart Height="262" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                   Margin="33,0,0,10" Name="columnChart" Title="Column Series Demo" 
                                   VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="360">

                <chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries  DependentValuePath="Value" Visibility="Visible"
                                        IndependentValuePath="Key" ItemsSource="{Binding ValueList}" />

                <chartingToolkit:Chart.LegendStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="Control">
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="0" />
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="0" />
                    </Style>
                </chartingToolkit:Chart.LegendStyle>

            </chartingToolkit:Chart>

            <Button Content="Data Clear" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="426,65,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click_Clear"/>
            <Button Content="Data Add" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="426,108,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click_Add"/>

        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the code

```
private void Button_Click_Clear(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var series in columnChart.Series.OfType<Series>())
    {
        series.DataContext = null;
    }
    columnChart.Series.Clear();
    dataToChart.Clear();
}
```

1. You're setting the `DataContext` to `null`, but you're not reassigning it afterwards, leaving the data feed broken.
2. The line `columnChart.Series.Clear()` wipes out the `ColumnSeries` you declared in XAML. Again, not reassigning causes the chart to remain blank.

You could overcome both issues using

```
private void Button_Click_Clear(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    dataToChart.Clear();
    foreach (var series in columnChart.Series.OfType<Series>())
    {
        series.DataContext = null;
        series.DataContext = dataToChart;
    }
}
```

Of course, in case of multiple series with different `DataContext`, you'd need to reassign the *right* `Input` to the corresponding `series.DataContext`.